# Cross-compiling external linux module: M=`pwd`directory not found

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, kernel-module

I'm compiling an external module against a complete kernel tree using CentOS. I've succesfully modified, cross-compiled, built and booted this kernel on a Beaglebone. I'm using the linaro tools (arm-gnueabihf-). I'm using the same typical Makefile structure to compile the module I've ever used since 2.6 came out. When running the make rule:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CC} -C $(KDIR) M=`pwd` modules
```

where `CC` and `KDIR` are properly set for my toolchain and my kernel src tree, kbuild properly changes dir to the `-C` (kernel src) dir, but when coming back (i.e. processing `M`) I get the following error:

```
scripts/Makefile.build:44: /home/foo/bar/
Makefile: No such file or directory
```

where `/home/foo/bar` is actually my current working directory, i.e. the proper outcome of `pwd`

Directly writing my pwd path in `M=` or using a make var instead of invoking `pwd` yields the same result (not a syntax problem)

Any idea?

Comment: I think it is missing /home/foo/bar/Makefile.  Check line 44 of $KDIR/scripts/Makefile.build

Comment: Solved: it was a problem with the "if" in my Makefile. I was using smt like this: `ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
obj-m += foo.o
else
<vars, make rules>`. Since the `ifneq` cond was false, obj-m was not being properly updated with the module, resulting in that error.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this ,as i dont know how is your make file.

create `Makefile in /home/foo/bar`

```
obj-m += hello.o
KERNELDIR=/home/vinay.hunachyal/build/clfs/sources/linux-3.9
all:
    make -C  $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean: 
    make -C $(KERNELDIR)  M=$(PWD) clean
```

In above Makefile edit KERNELDIR=(path-to-kernel-source)
also change obj-m +=(your module)

After this just build your module using

`make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-`